# How to count the number of columns in a line with python

Tags: python

I am writing a python code and I am trying to figure out which function would be the best to carry out the following task:

I want to say "if the number of words in a line isn't equal to 1, do stuff"

```
#Some code
words = line.split("\t")
if sum(words) != 1
#Do something

#Some code
words = line.split("\t")
if int(words) != 1
#Do something

#Some code
words = line.split("\t")
if len(words) != 1
#Do something
```

All of these commands return the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 10
if len(words) != 1
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: ...you're missing a colon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are missing colons after every "if" statement. Also, to get the number of elements in words, you should use len() instead of sum().

This

```
if sum(words) != 1
#Do something
```

Should be this:

```
if len(words) != 1:
#Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(len(line.split(" "))!=1) :
    do something
```

Comment: split already gives a list, this is not correct.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: `line.split()` will return a list, no need to `list()` it again.

Comment: @Ruben Though split returns a list the previous answer gives you right answer

Comment: Agreed, but a correct `output` isn't always a right `answer`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check length of spited list:

```
if len(words) != 1:
    #Do your stuff here
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys :)